# How to change the returnKeyType in react-native-gifted-chat?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I use GiftedChat from react-native-gifted-chat and I use the InputToolbar component to style the input. My problem is that I can't change the "enter" button on the keyboard with that. Should I use TextInput and make a separated button for Send instead of InputToolbar?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer but I will not delete this question because it took me a while to find one.
You can add textInputProps in the InputToolbar component:

```
 <InputToolbar
        textInputProps={{returnKeyType: 'send'}}
 />
```